SwiftUI Sign in with Apple
Have anyone encountered this error while checking the Apple authentication state?
Error checking credential state: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.AuthenticationServices.AuthorizationError error 1000.)
I can sign in with Apple, retrieve user's details such as e-mail and i can also log them out, it works perfectly fine. However checking for authentication state failing and i'm afraid i need to fix before submitting the app, this can lead to a rejection.
I have added the Sign in with Apple capabilities in my project.
I have checked the previous posts regarding this issue but no joy.
Thank you.
Here is the block checking for Apple authentication state:
func verifySignInWithAppleAuthenticationState() async {
        let appleIDProvider = ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider()
        
        guard let user = try? await Supabase.shared.client.auth.session.user else {
            print("DEBUG: No valid userID found.")
            return
        }
       
        print("DEBUG: Verifying Apple credential state for userID: \(user.id.uuidString)")
        
        do {
            let credentialState = try await appleIDProvider.credentialState(forUserID: user.id.uuidString)
            switch credentialState {
            case .authorized:
                break // The Apple ID credential is valid.
            case .revoked:
                self.errorMessage = AuthenticationErrors.credentialRevoked.localizedDescription
                await signOut()
            case .notFound:
                self.errorMessage = AuthenticationErrors.credentialNotFound.localizedDescription
                await signOut()
            default:
                break
            }
        } catch {
            print("DEBUG: Error checking credential state: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            self.errorMessage = AuthenticationErrors.unknownError(error).localizedDescription
        }
    }

Here is the DEBUG console:

Adding Sign in with Apple capabilities

Change (error.localizedDescription to (error. (error.localizedDescription doesn't provide anything useful to a developer only use it to show errors to the user.

Yeah you are right. However in this scenario i get this: Error checking credential state: Error Domain=com.apple.AuthenticationServices.AuthorizationError Code=1000 "(null).  I believe  Error 1000 is a generic error that indicates a failure in the authorization process. It doesn't provide much detail on its own

I think i'm better off removing this func and leave it like it is. However its not recommended since this func  ensures that the credential is still valid and has not been revoked or invalidated since the user last signed in...

If you have Supabase listening for revocations it isn't needed

Yes i do have Supabase listening for revocations. It is injected in the Environment. Thank you, you are right again lol...it is not needed

In SwiftUI there is the AuthenticationController https://developer.apple.com/documentation/AuthenticationServices/AuthorizationController
